# flexigrid on row click

Tags: jquery, flexigrid

How can I trigger a common action on a row click action the flexigrid way? I want when the row is clicked to redirect to http://localhost/view/40 (the value of ID) for the clicked row

```
            $("#flex1").flexigrid({
                url: 'http://localhost/index.php/get_data',
                dataType: 'json',
                method: 'GET',
                colModel : [
                        {display: 'ID', name : 'id', width : 40, sortable : true},
                        {display: 'A', name : 'a',  width : 40,  sortable : true},
                     singleSelect   {display: 'B', name : 'b', width : 40,  sortable : true},
                    ],
                sortname: "id",
                sortorder: "desc",
                showTableToggleBtn: false,
                resizable: false,                       
                useRp: true,
                rp: 30,                      
                singleSelect: true,
                usepager: true,
                width: 'auto',
                height: 100
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly how flexigrid works, but I use jqGrid, and commonly what I do is to just set these type of actions outside the grid. this does require a common markup naming convention, but I'm assuming flexigrid must do this.

so for example, you can take a look at your HTML in Firebug and see what classes or id might get assigned to the column for ID. maybe its a class like flexigrid-row-id or something like that

```
$('#flex1 tr[WHATEVER SELECTOR RENDERS IN YOUR GRID FOR THE ID COLUMN]').click(function(){
     // simulates similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
      window.location.replace("http://localhost/view/40");
});
```

just make sure you assign this event after your grid has completed/loaded

Answer (score -1):

This is how I do it..

I load the grid

```
jQuery("#sometable").flexigrid({
                url: 'http://localhost/get_data',
                dataType: 'json',
                colModel : [
                    {display: 'id', name : 'id', width : 40, sortable : true, align: 'center', hide: true},
                    {display: 'name ', name : 'Name', width : 150, sortable : false, align: 'left', hide: false},
                    {display: 'image', name : 'LogoName', width : 100, sortable : true, align: 'left', hide: false}
                    ],
                    sortname: "id",
                    sortorder: "desc",
                    usepager: true,
                    singleSelect: true,
                    title: 'Some title',
                    useRp: true,
                    rp: 10,
                    width: 1000,
                    nowrap: false,
                    height: 'auto',
                    onSuccess : sometableonSuccess
          });
```

and when it loads.. onSuccess triggers..

```
function sometableonSuccess(){
        jQuery('#sometable tr').each( function(){ 

                jQuery(this).click(function(){
                      //Get the id of the row
                      var id = jQuery(this).find("td:eq(0)").text(); 
                      //Do some action

                });                                        


            });
    }
```